# Java: How to create appmenu button like the orange one in Firefox?

Tags: java, swing, firefox

Windows version of Firefox has a special orange button combined with application title which replaces the traditional menu bar:

[image: Firefox orange button]

Is it possible to create something like this in Java? Or other formulated: how can I place a button in the title bar in Java?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For me it's usual JButton. Click on the button just shows JPopupMenu

Comment: @PradeepSimha If you think there are obvious ways which Andrej should have tried already, you'd better share those obvious ways.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-decorated-titlebar-jframe.html

Comment: @PradeepSimha That's an undecorated frame. It doesn't add the button to the title bar; it **removes the entire title bar**. Not what OP asked.

Comment: @PradeepSimha Actually nothing, because I never saw in Swing tools to work with the title bar.

Comment: @StanislavL One does not simply place a JButton in the title bar :-)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You cant change the title bar because it is OS dependent. But you can set your JFrame to undecorated(true) and create a custom title bar by creating a JPanel, adding it to the top of your frame.

Comment: Thanks. But building own title bar would be way to complex because I want the native title bar to persist...

Comment: +1 to answer. @Andrej well than you wont be able to add it as/to the title bar, look at adding it as another component maybe in place of menuBar

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has said, you cannot add a button to the standard title bar.

However, if you are willing to tolerate using the Metal look and feel, you can have it create a title bar for you, to which you can semi-reliably add components:

```
JButton button = new JButton(" Menu \u25be ");

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);

// Force creation of title bar components.
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
frame.pack();

JLayeredPane layeredPane = frame.getLayeredPane();
JComponent titlePane = (JComponent) layeredPane.getComponentAt(0, 0);
for (Component c : titlePane.getComponents()) {
    if (c instanceof Container &&
        ((Container) c).getLayout() instanceof DefaultMenuLayout) {

        int layer = layeredPane.getLayer(titlePane);
        layeredPane.setLayer(button, layer + 1);

        button.setLocation(c.getX() + c.getWidth() + 3, 1);
        Dimension size = button.getPreferredSize();
        size.height = Math.min(size.height, titlePane.getHeight() - 2);
        button.setSize(size);
        layeredPane.add(button);

        break;
    }
}
```

This will only work when using the Metal look and feel, since that is the only LookAndFeel class whose `getSupportsWindowDecorations` method returns true (I think).